# JavaScript-HTML form validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I was trying to validate a form using javascript but the form validation is not working. Not sure, if it's even been routing to the function. Here is the html form modal.

```
<div class="modal-body form">
                <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" ;>
                    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id" />
                    <div class="form-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Brand Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input required type="text" name="bname" id="brname" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Brand Origin</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input required type="text" name="origin" id="brorigin" class="form-control" placeholder="Origin">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Submit" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>

            </div>
```

And here is the javascript form validation script

```
function validateForm()
    {
        $('#btnSave').click(function()
        {

            var brname = document.getElementById("brname").value;
            var brorigin = document.getElementById("brorigin").value;
            if (brname.length == 0)
            {
                window.alert("You must enter a name.");
                brname.focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (brorigin.length == 0)
            {
                window.alert("You must enter the origin country");
                brorigin.focus();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

thanks..

**EDIT:** There was a prolem in the form model. The onclick event listener would save the form. The error alert was displayed when I moved the function inside the `$(document).ready(function(){` function

Comment: Have you tried changing 'x.length == 0' to 'x.length === 0'?

Comment: Have you tried moving the submit button inside the form tag?

Comment: Please specify "form validation is not working". What **exactly** goes wrong? What is the expected result from your code?

Comment: I don't see you calling `validateForm()`. Try to move the click event code out of the function.

Comment: Move the submit button inside the form tag ; put on the onclick event : "validateForm(); save()" ; remove the onclick event from validateForm(); drop the onsubmit event on the form tag

Comment: @NeilHibbert yes i tried that too...

Comment: @thenewbie and what happened with the submit/input inside the form tag? Was the validateForm() function called?

Comment: @NeilHibbert yes the function was called, the message was displayed but the form was submitted... I found the error, it was on the submit button, the onclick event listener was active... thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

The first time you try to submit the form, it will add click event listener to the submit button, but there is nothing to stop the form from submitting. Move the click listener out of the function, and ditch the function. And, remove `onsubmit` attribute from the form.

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() {

        var brname = document.getElementById("brname").value;
        var brorigin = document.getElementById("brorigin").value;
        if (brname.length == 0)
        {
            window.alert("You must enter a name.");
            brname.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (brorigin.length == 0)
        {
            window.alert("You must enter the origin country");
            brorigin.focus();
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: it worked, but only half way.. It did displayed the message but the entry was added

Answer (score 0):

The code of `validateForm()` is going to be executed only when you click on the submit button btnSave. The `validateForm()` function just register an event handler on the click, but the click is happened before the registration of the event handler. And `validateForm` returns undefined probably. Try to put the code of validateForm or in `$(document).ready()` or directly inside the function, **without** the click event.`

```
function validateForm()
{
        var brname = document.getElementById("brname").value;
        var brorigin = document.getElementById("brorigin").value;
        if (brname.length == 0)
        {
            window.alert("You must enter a name.");
            brname.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (brorigin.length == 0)
        {
            window.alert("You must enter the origin country");
            brorigin.focus();
            return false;
        }

}
```

**EDIT:**
The `save()` function is called even if the `validateForm` returns `false` because you call that function on `onclick` event of the submit button.
Try to call `save()` in `validateForm` after both `if`

Comment: i already tried by putting it directly inside the function. it didn't work

Comment: yes doing that worked... Thanks for pointing out about the `save()` function

Answer (score 0):

updated code here try it now.

```
<div class="modal-body form">
                    <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal" name="myForm">
                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="id" />
                        <div class="form-body">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Brand Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <input required type="text" name="bname" id="brname" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Brand Origin</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <input required type="text" name="origin" id="brorigin" class="form-control" placeholder="Origin">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>

                </div>



$('#btnSave').click(function()
                {

                    var brname =$('#brname').val()
                    var brorigin = $('#brorigin').val()
                    if (brname == '')
                    {
                        window.alert("You must enter a name.");
                        brname.focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (brorigin == '')
                    {
                        window.alert("You must enter the origin country");
                        brorigin.focus();
                        return false;
                    }

            return true
                });
```

Comment: i tried putting it inside the $(document).ready(function()), and it did work half way... it displayed the messaged but the blank form was submitted...
 
I also tried removing the function and only the $("#btnSave") event, this way it did not work

Answer (score 0):

very simple follow w3school this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp